# sourceanalyzer: command not found (mac)

Tags: java, fortify

I just installed a newer version of the Fortify package (4.30) but every time I try to use the command line to manually scan a project, I get an error that sourceanalyzer isn't an available option. I've tried reinstalling and I still cant get it to work. I can only scan in audit workbench. I never had this problem with earlier versions of Fortify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start /Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.30/bin/sourceanalyzer
2. Open a new tab and run your fortify bash script or run sourceanalyzer command from here

It still will not run in my other terminal windows, but will only run in this one.

Comment: I was having the same issue where I was not able to run the sourceanalyzer from jenkins powershell and this helped me. I added following code and it worked as a charm  ```&'//path/to/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.30/bin/sourceanalyzer.exe' sourcenalayzer -v```

Answer (score 5):

Add this line to your ~/.bash_profile

```
alias sourceanalyzer="/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.xx/bin/sourceanalyzer"
```

Note: Where it says HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.xx, put the version you are using here. Make sure your path is working and you shouldn't have to worry about it anymore. Don't forget to update this when you update your fortify application.

After this is done, just run the following command in your terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

that will reload the bash_profile in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Is HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.30/bin in your path system variable? For Windows, look at system properties, advanced, environment variables, then edit the PATH system variable and look for the entry for 4.30/bin.